# parsing a large text file into 140 character tweets

Tags: php, parsing, text

I want to parse a large text file so that it breaks into a new line at 140 characters... or the character limit on one tweet. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What language would you be interested in using?

Comment: @zrvan most likely PHP since I'm trying to eventually run the script as a cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about where the split occurs (it could be in the middle of a word, or the like):

```
define ('TWEET_SIZE', 140);
$parts = str_split ($data, TWEET_SIZE);
$new = implode ("\n", $parts);
```

**UPDATE**
Something like this:

```
define ('TWEET_SIZE', 140); // set the size of each segment
$data = file_get_contents ('<path to file>'); // load the data from file
$parts = str_split ($data, TWEET_SIZE); // split the data
$new = implode ("\n", $parts); // put it back together with newlines
file_put_contents ('<path to new file>', $data); // put in new file (if needed)
```

Comment: any way I could implement this from an external file?

also, cutting off exactly at 140 isn't ideal, as I would rather have it cut off at 140 minus the last full word (so if the last word goes over 140 characters, make that part of the next tweet)

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList tweetList = new ArrayList();

while(string.length > 0)
{
     if(string.length > 139)
     {
          tweetList.add(string.substring(0, 139);
          string = string.substring(140,string.length - 1);
     }
     else
     {
         tweetList.add(string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
         string = "";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much shorter: :)

```
String[] tweets = yourLongString.split("(?<=\\G.{140})");
```

Ooops, didn't read the php constraint. This is Java.